# Square-taper crank wobble/movement in only one spot

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, square-taper

For square-taper aluminum cranks:

When my drive-side crank is in the 12:00/highest position and the non-drive side in the 6:00/lowest position, there is slight play between both cranks (it rotates transversely/outward about 1mm) It's only in this one spot. Is this a bottom bracket going out? Last time my BB went out it was sliding side to side.

I've tried tightening the crank bolts but they are snug.

Comment: can you feel this play with the cranks removed from the spindle?

Comment: Is this an open/loose bearing setup?   I'd suspect wear in the cups/cones.   Maybe worth upgrading to a cartridge-based BB.

Comment: @PaulH I haven't removed the cranks. Currently on tour and don't want to make things worse till I'm near a city. If there is play, what does that indicate?

Comment: @Criggie I believe it is a cartridge. https://www.interlocracing.com/shop/ird-qb-95-bottom-bracket-4057

Comment: If you’re on tour, there’s nothing to be done but ride to the nearest shop and have them assess it.

Answer (score -1):

sounds like worn Bottom Bracket /crank bearings.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider editing your answer to explain why you believe the problem is worn bottom bracket bearings. A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.